# Using an existing user table for phpBB authentication

Tags: authentication, phpbb3

I have an existing application with its own user table.  I'd like to add phpBB 3.1 to the application, but the question is how to do this without moving all user functions to phpBB (via whole site integration) and without maintaining separate user tables for the same user set (creating  users in phpBB automagically).

Is there a relatively easy way of pointing phpBB to an existing user table for forum logins?

Answer (score 0):

For old versions, this wiki [page](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins) helped me to implement an external provider.

In version `3.1`, the directory `phpBB/includes/auth/` has been moved to `phpBB/phpbb/auth/provider` and there is a [new documentation chapter](https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/dev/31x/extensions/tutorial_authentication.html#authentication-providers).

You could create your own provider by extending `\phpbb\auth\provider\base` and implementing the [provider_interface](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/phpbb/auth/provider/provider_interface.php).

Here is a [good template](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/phpbb/auth/provider/db.php) to duplicate with you own table. This is the internal standard db provider.

To declare the new provider you will create, the good practice is to create an extension and inject your new one. As example, here is a [github project](https://github.com/oneall/social-login-phpbb/tree/master/%5B%20%3E%3D%203.1.%20%5D%20EXTENSION/oneall/sociallogin). It declare an external provider for social Network. The provider must be added to `services.yml` like in all Symfony Project.

If you don't want to create an extension, (this is not a good practice) you could edit [services_auth.yml file](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/3bde3cf45a5104347ce431f6f2204bc05d31f9b5/phpBB/config/default/container/services_auth.yml) by adding your own provider :

```
services: #do not add this line
    auth.provider.db2:
        class: acme\demo\auth\provider\db2
        arguments:
            - '@dbal.conn'
        tags:
            - { name: auth.provider }
```

Comment: Did you end up using social media for your external provider or a local user table?